# Is Android Switch widget text positioned 1 pixel too high with respect to baseline?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm aligning a text view and a switch by baseline. However, in the end result, the bottom of text view text and switch text is misaligned by one pixel. See the gap between the bottom of letter "RE" and the horizontal purple line. Is there a way to compensate this so that the bottom of two strings are perfectly aligned?

[image]

Comment: OK, let's suppose the user is going to stare at the device screen with a **magnifier lens**... add a 1px padding to one of the Views?

Comment: You can add 1px paddingTop, but Why so serious about this ?

Comment: It's actually easily noticeable without using hierarchy viewer.

Comment: BTW, this is implemented by align the text view ("SYNC") relative to the switch ("RE") using **baseline**. So padding doesn't really work. In fact, I can't really think of anything that would fix this. It seems, the fact that text doesn't sit right on baseline is a bug in Switch widget.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the `Switch` widget and override the `getBaseline()` method. Then you can return any value you want.

Here's what TextView (and Switch, by inheritance) is doing to calculate baseline :

```
@Override
public int getBaseline() {
    if (mLayout == null) {
        return super.getBaseline();
    }

    int voffset = 0;
    if ((mGravity & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) != Gravity.TOP) {
        voffset = getVerticalOffset(true);
    }

    return getExtendedPaddingTop() + voffset + mLayout.getLineBaseline(0);
}
```